# ReadAsAsync deserializing HttpResponseMessage result

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, httpresponse

This queston may possible duplicated but I am calling a service as the following below :

```
   HttpClient httpClinet = new HttpClient();
   httpClinet.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
   httpClinet.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
   var str = "XrayService.asmx/GetOrdData?" + string.Format("ordId={0}&code={1}", range.ordId, range.code);
   HttpResponseMessage response; 
   httpClinet.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://172.16.203.27:6043/"); 
   response = httpClinet.GetAsync(str).Result;
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         var caseInfos = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<PI>>().Result;//Here is exception
```

everything is going fine, but when I want to run `ReadAsAsync` I got the exception as below:

> Error:System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 5. Expecting element 'ArrayOfPI' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SATA_DTOs'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'PI', namespace ''. 
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlReader reader)
>      at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
>      at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

I am testing that service by [Google Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and see the result as :

Status : 200 OK

Response Header:

```
cache-control: private, max-age=0
content-length: 360
content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
x-aspnet-version:4.0.30319
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Sun, 03 Dec 2017 08:37:21 GMT
```

and OutPut :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PI>
<ordId>950177248</ordId>
<fnm>بهسا</fnm>
<lnm>حسنی</lnm>
<fthNm>علی</fthNm>
<pId>p2535154</pId>
<sex>F</sex>
<brthD>2003-02-05</brthD>
<addrs />
<nId>0025351540</nId>
<srvNm>|دندان بصورت پانورک</srvNm>
<rfrPhy>مهرزاد اميري-41853</rfrPhy>
 </PI>
```

I also decorated DTO like :

```
namespace SATA_DTOs
{
    [DataContract(Name = "PI")]
    public class PI
    {
        [DataMember] public string ordId { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string fnm { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string lnm { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string fthNm { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string pId { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string sex { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string brthD { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string addrs { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string nId { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string srvNm { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string rfrPhy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Just as another try I want to get the result here either `JSON` or `XML` but this is also does not make difference:

```
List<PI> model = null;
var client = new HttpClient();
var task = client.GetAsync(httpClinet.BaseAddress.ToString() + str)
      .ContinueWith((taskwithresponse) =>
       {
           var response1 = taskwithresponse.Result;
           var jsonString = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                  m_Logging.Log(SharedLib.LoggingMode.Prompt, "JSON string created {0}...", jsonString);
           jsonString.Wait();
           model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PI>>(jsonString.Result);
        });
task.Wait();
```

Comment: Try changing DataContractName to "ArrayOfPI". Also, do not block on aysnc calls with  `.Result`. If you can't do proper async then use a synchronous API, not HttpClient.

Comment: In this particular case, you will have to read as string then load the xml, inspect the first node to determine if result is single object or collection and then deseiralize the xml accordingly based on type

Comment: @Crowcoder I think there is no difference either you call `GetAsync(str).Result` or `Get(str)` .

Comment: If you leave `ordId` off the query string do you get a collection of PI back?

Comment: @Aria, there is a big difference unless this is a console app. At best it is a waste of resources, at worst you cause a deadlock. You should `await` async calls or not make async calls.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes you are right I am convinced!!, but there may several records with same `ordId` in system so it may  returns a list, but about your first comment I think changing DataContractName  to `ArrayOfPI` doesn't make any sense!!

Comment: @Aria given the dynamic nature of the response you will need to inspect it first before trying to deserialize it. otherwise you will have to code defensively and wrap them in try/catch for either case.

Comment: @Aria after your last update now you need to clarify. Are you suppose to get back XML or JSON? the question is now unclear.

Comment: @Nkosi, Update section is not important, I just want tell you I tried to get the result as another solution but get that exception also.

Comment: @Aria here is the problem. when you use `ReadAsAsync` the framework tries to interpret the desired type for deserialization using the provided media type formatter. You have `IEnumerable<>` so it assumes that the content being read is a collection based on standards. In your example a single object is being returned while you tell it to expect a collection so it fails. I am telling you to check for collection and if that fails then check for single object.

Comment: @Nkosi Yes I think so the problem is something like you said, unfortunately I can't debug step by step, I should do the patch by replacing related dll, let me try your  posted solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many copy pasting patch on server and improving the log I finally resolve the problem,

As the last try which [@NKosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi) suggested with little changes:

```
var response1 = httpClinet.GetAsync(str).Result;
IEnumerable<PI> caseInfos1 = Enumerable.Empty<PI>();
try
{
    caseInfos1 = response1.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<PI>>().Result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        m_Logging.Log(SharedLib.LoggingMode.Error, "IEnumerable failed, EXP:{0}", ex);
        var singleObject = response1.Content.ReadAsAsync<PI>().Result;
        if (singleObject != null)
        {
            m_Logging.Log(SharedLib.LoggingMode.Error, "singleObject succeeded...");
            caseInfos1 = new[] { singleObject };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        m_Logging.Log(SharedLib.LoggingMode.Error, "singleObject failed, EXP:{0}", exp);
    }
}
```

I crossed with the below exception also:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 5. Expecting element 'ArrayOfPI' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SATA_DTOs'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'PI', namespace ''....
>
> .....

as the exception mentioned it can't be able to deserialize the result I guessed the out put type may is `text/html` not `text/xml` although [Rest Client Tester](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) specified it as `text/xml`,

for this reason I came to this conclusion to use `ReadAsStringAsync` and deserialize it to `PI`, so by the below snipped code I finally get the result:

```
PI caseInfos = null;
try
{
    string strasd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    m_Logging.Log(SharedLib.LoggingMode.Prompt, "ReadAsStringAsync() result:{0}", strasd);
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(PI));
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(strasd))
        caseInfos = (PI)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    m_Logging.Log(SharedLib.LoggingMode.Prompt, "Deserializing caseInfos model succeeded...");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    m_Logging.Log(SharedLib.LoggingMode.Error, "creating model failed, EXP:{0}", ex);
}
```

I appreciate all crossed this question especially those who shared his/her knowledge in this discussion!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is can be quite confusing. This might seem obvious the eye but still, not understandable to some.

Look at this line:

```
var caseInfos = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<PI>>().Result
```

You are rendering the result as PI, which results in `<pi>` tag.

**Thus, you get the following error:**

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1
>   position 5. Expecting element 'ArrayOfPI' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SATA_DTOs'.. Encountered
>   'Element' with name 'PI', namespace ''

The solution is this,

change your data contract **and** your class name:

```
namespace SATA_DTOs
{
    [DataContract(Name = "ArrayOfPI")]
    public class ArrayOfPI
    {
        [DataMember] public string ordId { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string fnm { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string lnm { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string fthNm { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string pId { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string sex { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string brthD { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string addrs { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string nId { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string srvNm { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string rfrPhy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then assign it like **this**:

```
 var caseInfos = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ArrayOfPI>>().Result
```

Thus, you will receive this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfPI>
<ordId>950177248</ordId>
<fnm>بهسا</fnm>
<lnm>حسنی</lnm>
<fthNm>علی</fthNm>
<pId>p2535154</pId>
<sex>F</sex>
<brthD>2003-02-05</brthD>
<addrs />
<nId>0025351540</nId>
<srvNm>|دندان بصورت پانورک</srvNm>
<rfrPhy>مهرزاد اميري-41853</rfrPhy>
 </ArrayOfPI>
```

Which is what the serialization looks for and expects to find.

Comment: I've got the same exception `Expecting element 'ArrayOfArrayOfPI' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SATA_DTOs'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'PI', namespace ''.`

Answer (score 0):

When using `ReadAsAsync` the framework tries to interpret the desired type for deserialization using the provided media type formatter.

You have `IEnumerable<PI>` so it assumes that the content being read is a collection `ArrayOfPI` based on standards.

In your example a single object is being returned while you tell it to expect a collection so it fails.

I suggest checking for collection and if that fails then check for single object given the dynamic nature of the responses that can be returned.

Simplified example

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PI>> GetDataAsync() {
    var httpClinet = buildClient();
    var str = buildRequestUrl();
    var response = await httpClinet.GetAsync(str);
    IEnumerable<PI> caseInfos = Enumerable.Empty<PI>();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        try {
            caseInfos = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<PI>>();
        } catch {
            //Log?
        }
        if (caseInfos == null) {
            try {
                var singleObject = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<PI>();
                if (singleObject != null) {
                    caseInfos = new[] { singleObject };
                }
            } catch {
                //Log?
            }
        }
    }
    return caseInfos;
}
```

Comment: It does not work also, non of that `try` block didn't work.