# Deserialising a JSON response from a httpclient Post request into a custom object

Tags: c#, json, api, deserialization, httprequest

I want to call a httpClient Post method and put the JSON response, which is an array consisting 2 double and put them as respective field in an object.
e.g. the response is:

```
[12345, 56789]
```

I want to put `12345` as newObject.firstPrice, and `56789` as newObject.secondPrice, and retrieve them to do some computation later on. However,  I am not sure how to do it.

I have seen 2 ways of deserialising a JSON response on the internet.

**1st example:**

seems like I should create a newObject and use `<IEnumerable<newObject>>` & `for each` to do so?
But what should I put inside the `{}` in `for each`?

```
namespace ConsoleProgram
{
    public class DataObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // HTTP request goes here
            
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // **Deserialisation into the Dataobject?**
                var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<DataObject>>().Result;  
                foreach (var d in dataObjects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.Name);
                }
            }
               ...
```

**2nd example:**

(taken from the question [ReadAsAsync deserializing HttpResponseMessage result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617838/readasasync-deserializing-httpresponsemessage-result))

```
PI caseInfos = null;
try
{
    string strasd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    m_Logging.Log(SharedLib.LoggingMode.Prompt, "ReadAsStringAsync() result:{0}", strasd);
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(PI));
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(strasd))
        caseInfos = (PI)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    m_Logging.Log(SharedLib.LoggingMode.Prompt, "Deserializing caseInfos model succeeded...");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    m_Logging.Log(SharedLib.LoggingMode.Error, "creating model failed, EXP:{0}", ex);
}
```

The 2nd way seems more complicated, may I ask is it even the correct way to go for?

Answer (score 2):

could be

```
List<double> data = null;
 // or 
double[] data = null;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var  json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

  data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<double>>(json); 

     // or 
    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double[]>(json); 
}

     if (data!=null)
{
    var firstPrice= data[0];
    var secondPrice= data[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works. May I ask a follow up question? I want to print both `data[0]` and `data[1]` when I click a button in my application (the button's method code is located in another folder). 
However, I cannot access to `data[0]` nor `data[1]` in the button_cick method, I cannot do so anywhere outside of the `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {...}` code. 
May I ask how can I import `data[0]` and `data[1]` to another method and print it out?

Comment: @delala I updated my answer. Now data is defined outside of if scope.  So you can acess it.

Answer (score -1):

Serge's answer works, but if you wanted to specifically convert those values into a object with `FirstPrice` and `SecondPrice` properties, you could deserialize to an `IList<double>` and then create an object from the deserialized value (*This assumes that you are getting exactly 2 double values back. You might need to do additional checks in any other situation*)

```c#
public class Result
{
    public Result()
    {
    }

    public Result(double firstPrice, double secondPrice)
    {
        this.FirstPrice = firstPrice;
        this.SecondPrice = secondPrice;
    }

    public double FirstPrice { get; set; }

    public double SecondPrice { get; set; }

    public static Result FromResponse(IList<double> values)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(values);

        return values.Count == 2
            ? new Result(values[0], values[1])
            : throw new ArgumentException(nameof(values), "Expected 2 double values");
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(FirstPrice)}: {this.FirstPrice}, {nameof(SecondPrice)}: {this.SecondPrice}";
    }
}
```

Then when you're handling the `HttpResponseMessage`, you can pass the content to the static method.

```c#
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var content = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IList<double>>(responseContent);
    var result = Result.FromResponse(content);
}
```